# How to fix 'unknown_certificate' error of a self-signed TLS certificate in java play framework

Tags: java, ssl, playframework

I am trying to implement the HTTPS on an internal web application which uses Play framework (version 2.5) as a Backend framework and Angular as Frontend and I have created a self signed certificate with Keytool following the Play framework documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CertificateGeneration.

Then I save the '.crt' file in cacerts (java keystore) and provide the .jks when starting the application with these additional commands:

`-Dplay.server.https.keyStore.path="path-to-jks-file"

 and -Dplay.server.https.keyStore.password="the-password-here"`

But after trying to make a request to the server I get an error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown (image below)

Although the handshake happens after that and the HTTPS works correctly. Any ideas how to solve this issue

[Link to error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiKpf.png)

Comment: "while running the application" - what happens when you restart the application?

Comment: @J_D  this error happens whenever I make a request, restarting the application doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Great! "while running the application" was ambiguous.

Comment: Check out this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485987/ssl-exception-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-certif

Comment: Yes you were right, I have just edited that part. Thanks!

Comment: I just read the post you recommended and I couldn't find the relation to my problem.The error happens whether I provide a certificate for the client or not. Could it be that the browser tls mechanism that checks for the validity of the certificate is triggering this error. An additional info: In Firefox the error shown is 'bad_certificate' instead of 'unknown_certificate' - in Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue now. The problem with Chrome Browser was on 'Subject Alternative Name' missing, which is required from Chrome 58+ and that caused the error during the tls handshake. After adding SAN property to the certificate the problem is gone.
I posted this answer to help anyone who might have the same problem...